# Typescript - correct way to set a string based on string comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to check if a string is equal to another string and set a new string based on this condition.

```
 private myFunction( myString: string ) {

    if (myString != "someString") {
      let path:string = "/*/POST/A";
    }
    else{
      let path:string = "/*/POST/note/B";

    }
   (do something with path here)
```

Not sure the above is correct actually finding it pretty hard to find a decent example of this and completely new to typescript/ javascript.

Comment: `let path = "/*/POST/note/B"; if (myString != "someString") { path = "/*/POST/A"; }`?

Comment: yea that works comment as answer i will accept

Comment: You have to define your `let` variable before any condition if u want to do something with your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) so you’re not declaring the variable inside the conditional:

```js
const path:string = myString === “someString” ? “option a” : “option b”
```

Comment: I like this, so the option a is if the string is equal to someString?

Comment: Yes. It takes this form: `condition ? value if true : value if false`

Answer (score 2):

`let` variables are *block-scoped* - they only exist within the block you declare them. So declaring `let path` inside of the if block or the else block won't allow you to use it later outside of the if/else.

All you need to do is *declare* it in the scope you want to use it and *assign* it in the if/else.

```
let path: string;
if (myString != "someString") {
  path = "/*/POST/A";
} else {
  path = "/*/POST/note/B";
}
//use path here
```